# My armor stand continues to keep disappearing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a armor stand on survival, and my stand keeps disappearing from the place I put it. I have all my diamond armor on it and I have no Idea what to do. My armor stand is placed on a dirt floor. Does anyone know how to fix this glitch and why it has been happening?

Comment: Assuming you're in survival singleplayer, could you take a screenshot of the environment around the armorstand? If you're in multiplayer, it could be because of other players.

Comment: A video wouls be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you on singleplayer World or a multiplayer server??

if hou are on a multiplayer server it might be a bug from the clearlag thingy cuz the armorstad Count as an entitie and not a block so it might remove it

if you was on singleplayer it might be the invischunk glitch
that is a glitch that happens alot and it mostly just remove a whole chunk and when you try enter it you will jsut dive in the air but also sometimes it will happen as you can still see the blocks but when you try Place/break anyblock at this chunk it will just lag

Hopefully that helped you!

Comment: It is on the x-box on singleplayer server